# How to send data to a server application

Tags: php, forms, api, web-services

I'm trying to transform an old app in a Web Service. My customers should be able to send some data, like:

```
hotel = "London North", stars = 3, rooms = 57, presences = 12000
```

in any form that I could process with a server app (PHP on Python) and I could send back to the customer with data enriched by some calculation my app does, like:

```
average room occupation = 15%, yearly shower gel consumption = 20000
```

Since I don't have to develop the remote page (except a simple demo), I thought about sending a JSON file and receiving another JSON file, or maybe posting an XML file by mail.

Do you think there's an alternative to an HTML form followed by the creation of an XML file?
Does anyone has a link to some resources to resolve this challenge?

Comment: You are in control. If you want to receive input as JSON then tell the user that. If you want to be flexible, give the user an option to send you like `output=JSON` or `output="XML` you are the boss. what ever makes sense to you. An API is not Rocket Science, its just a subroutine that is accessible to all, or you can make it require a login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a [RESTful API](https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/api/restful-api) is exactly what you need.

First of all, it's the most widely adopted standard, so you will have lots of libraries and frameworks for both your web service and any clients that may want to hook to it.

In the second place, it's extremely easy to understand. Communication to your server is made in plain HTTP requests, using JSON data as the request body and the server response, making data simple to handle.

For example, in case you want to send the hotel data from your example above, you would send a POST request to a new route from your server with the following JSON body:

```
{
    "hotel": "London North", 
    "stars": 3,
    "rooms": 57, 
    "presences": 12000
}
```

And you would get an HTTP 200 response with the following body:

```
{
    "average_room_occupation": 0.15, 
    "yearly_shower_gel_consumption": 20000
}
```